# How would I show that $SO^{+}(n,1) / SO(n) \approx \mathbb{H}$?

Tags: lie-groups, quotient-group

Write $\mathbb{R}^{n,1} \approx \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}$. Consider the matrix $I_{n,1} = \mathrm{diag}(1, 1, \ldots, 1, -1)$.

Consider the following Lie groups:

$SO(n) = \left\{ \ A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})\ |\ A^{T}A = A A^{T} = I,\ \mathrm{det}(A) = 1\ \right\}$

$SO^{+}(n,1) = \left\{\ A \in M_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}(\mathbb{R})\ |\ A^{T} I_{n,1} A = I_{n,1},\ \mathrm{det}(A) = 1 \ \mathrm{and}\ A_{(n+1)(n+1)}>0 \ \right\}$

$\mathbb{H} = \left\{\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n,1}\ |\ B(x,x) = -1, \ x_{n+1} > 0\ \right\}$

With the bilinear form $B(x,y) = - x_{n+1} y_{n+1} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j} y_{j}$.

I'm trying to show that $SO^{+}(n,1) / SO(n) \approx \mathbb{H}$. The way I think I should do this is using the first isomorphism theorem (I don't know how else to do it!).

So I believe I need to find a mapping $f : \mathbb{H} \to SO^{+}(n,1)$ which is surjective and such that $\mathrm{ker}(f) = SO(n)$. If I could find such a mapping then I'd be done - but what is this mapping?

My thinking is to define $f$ as:
$$
f(\mathbb{x},x_{n+1}) = \left[ \begin{matrix} \alpha(\mathbf{x}) & \mathbf{x} \\ \mathbf{x}^{T} & x_{n+1}^{2} \end{matrix} \right]
$$

But I don't know how to define the function $\alpha$ (which I think should be a surjective mapping onto $SO(n)$).

Can someone help me out here? Or is there a simpler way to show that $SO^{+}(n,1) / SO(n) \approx \mathbb{H}$?

Comment: In what sense are you regarding the objects $\text{SO}^+(n,1)/\text{SO}(n)$ and $\mathbb{H}$?  Are you thinking of them as sets, so that $\approx$ means "in bijection"?  Or are you thinking of them as manifolds, so that $\approx$ means "diffeomorphic"?  Or maybe you mean as homogeneous spaces, so $\approx$ means "$\text{SO}^+(n,1)$-equivariantly diffeomorphic"?  It sounds like you're regarding these two objects as groups.  But I'm not sure how you're doing that, because you haven't said what the group structures are.  (In fact, I don't think these objects are naturally groups at all.)

Comment: Without further specification, I think the most reasonable interpretation of this problem is that $\text{SO}^+(n,1)/\text{SO}(n)$ and $\mathbb{H}$ are to be regarded as "sets with $\text{SO}^+(n,1)$-actions."  In that case, you have to show that $\text{SO}^+(n,1)$ does two things: (1) it acts transitively on $\mathbb{H}$, and (2) its stabilizer at any point of $\mathbb{H}$ is isomorphic to $\text{SO}(n)$.  Showing these two points will imply (by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem) that $\text{SO}^+(n,1)/\text{SO}(n) \approx \mathbb{H}$ in the category of "sets with $\text{SO}^+(n,1)$-actions."